# Style issues with algorithm2e and listofalgorithms

Tags: algorithm2e

I have an issue regarding the heading of \listofalgorithms.

```
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\begingroup
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\renewcommand{\numberline}{Algorithm~\oldnumberline}
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmcfname}{{List of Algorithms}}
\listofalgorithms
\endgroup
```

Using above code snippet, I get different styles for the heading of the different lists.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I use algorithm2e

```
\usepackage[english,ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
```

Furthermore, I use a *.cls, which exploits the class report.

Unfortunately, I was not able to isolate the core of the error and thus I cannot present a MWE here.

How is it possible to change the style of the heading for 
    \listofalgorithms
? 
I already tried to use

```
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmcfname}{List of Algorithms}
```

but this only changes the used letters and not the style of the letters.
Small letters still appear as capital letters.

My next idea was just to use

```
\renewcommand{\listalgorithmcfname}{~}
```

Then, I wanted to hard-code my one heading, however, \listofalgorithms begins on a new page.

**Edit:**
I found the source of this issue.

I use the package fncychap to change the style of chapter headings.

```
\usepackage[Bjarne]{fncychap}
```

For the heading, \listofalgorithms uses this style rather than the style that is used by \listoftables and \listoffigures.

My current workaround is:

```
\begingroup
\let\oldnumberline\numberline
\renewcommand{\numberline}{Algorithm~\oldnumberline}
~
~
~
{\section*{\huge\textbf{List of Algorithms}}} 
\vspace{.7cm}
\makeatletter
\@starttoc{loa}
\makeatother
% \listofalgorithms
\endgroup
```

So, I manually change the style and placement of the heading.

Is there a more general way to use the same style than for the other lists?

Hopefully, somebody knows a solution for my problem.

Comment: This is an old post, but as you did not provide a minimal working example, this migh have mad people relunctant to provide help. If you are still interested in an anwser please complete it with such an example. See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for more information